# You have to choose an hour that isn't already taken by someone

Tags: american-english, british-english

I always have problem using the word **already**, or simply have trouble with tenses;
in the first place, is the sentence in the question correct? secondly, when should we use **already**, can we use it in present tense?

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence is correct as it stands. "Already" can be used with the present tense:

> I am already in London.
>
> I already play tennis, so I'd like to learn squash.

You could consider using the present perfect in your example:

> You have to choose an hour that hasn't already been taken by someone else.

Comment: 'Is not already taken' sounds a bit odd to me, and as you suggested 'hasn't already been taken' sounds better.

Comment: They're both correct and sound natural. Once the hour has *been* taken, it then *is* taken - that is, in the state of having been taken.